# MySQL count based off specific criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL data set that looks like this:

**Tables**

```
City
Country
CountryLanguage
...
```

**The following query to get a result of every region in Europe**

2a: `select DISTINCT Region from Country where Continent="Europe"`

What I need to now query is:

> For each of the regions, show the number of countries in that region

I've tried a few things, none of which have worked - I have no idea, if anyone can give me any direction?

**(Table schema)**

```
ID | Name  | Continent     | Region
1  | Aruba | North America | Carribean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this query-

```
select continent, region, count(*) as "No of Country"  from Country where continent like 'Europe' group by region;
```

this query can help you more if you want to varify

```
select continent, region, group_concat(Name) as "List of Country" ,count(*) as "No of Country"  from Country where continent like 'Europe' group by region;
```